# Constraining the total volume in Finite Element Methods

Tags: finite-element, constraints, weak-solution

I have a diffusion problem which can be broken down to be:

$-\Delta u = f(u) $    on $\Omega ~/~ \Omega_{int}$

$u = 1$  on $\Omega_{int}$

Note that this is an **internal** Dirichlet constraint to the value 1.0 in the center circle, unlike the standard textbook examples with homogeneous boundary conditions. (see picture) Think of it like a source in the middle, which diffuses into the domain with f(u) = u(1-u) being a logistic growthterm. I want that reaction to stop at a certain maximum total mass.

---

I want to impose an **integral condition** which will stabilize the solution:

$P(u) = \int_{\Omega}  u  ~ dx =V_{tot}$

Now, I tried to read into the problem, and I find that it is possible to add penalty terms to the bilinear form of the finite element discretization, but I am deeply puzzled as to how to properly define the penalty term so that my Newton solver will behave correctly.

Multiplying with a test function v, integrating over the domain we may formulate the problem without the volume constraint like this:

find u, v so that

$ r(u,v) = a(u,v)+ l(v) = 0 $

where $r(u,v)$ is a global residuum (To be minimized by the Newton solver), $a(u,v)$ is the canonical discretisation of the diffusive term and $l(v)$ the disc. of the reaction term.

---

Now in the language of Lagrange multipliers, we have a functional $r(u,v)$ and a constraint $P(u)$ on the volume so that the new Functional would look like:

$L(u,v,\lambda)= a(u,v)+ l(v) -\lambda(P(u)-V_{tot}) = 0 $

- How do I apply this to my Finite Element Method in a clean way?
- How would I determine $\lambda$?
- Is there any readable literature on how to construct volume-constraints via penalty terms?
- Is there a more readable/hands-on literature/Paper on Lagrange multipliers in the context of FE-Methods than the work of [Ivo Babuska](https://gdz.sub.uni-goettingen.de/id/PPN362160546_0020?tify=%7B%22view%22%3A%22info%22%2C%22pages%22%3A%5B183%5D%7D)?
- How do I make sure that the penalty term, which will probably contain a domain-wide integral will not mess up my Newtonian (since the necessary calculations for the Jacobian are no longer local)?

[image]

Comment: If you have $u=1$ on $\Omega_{int}$, then the solution is equivalent to the one of the Laplace equation on $\Omega-\bar\Omega_{int}$ with boundary conditions equal to 1 on $\partial\Omega_{int}$. This might be the easier way to solve the problem -- just cut out $\Omega_{int}$.

Comment: Hi. I don't think that's it. If I do not constrain the total volume, then the domain would simply 'fill up' diffusively until the solution reaches u=1 everywhere. Note that I keep the outer boundary of the box unconstrained! Thanks for answering!

Comment: Well, if $u=1$ in $\Omega_{int}$, then $u=1$ on $\partial \Omega_{int}$. And if $-\Delta u=f$ in $\Omega \cup \Omega_{int}$, then also $-\Delta u=f$ in $\Omega - \Omega_{int}$.

Comment: I'll also note that you can't have  $-\Delta u=f$ in $\Omega_{int}$ and $u=1$ in $\Omega_{int}$ at the same time, unless $f=0$ in $\Omega_{int}$.

Comment: Hi. You are right about the internal not having the $- \Delta~ u = f~ in ~\Omega_{int}$. I messed up the notation there. It should be  $-\Delta ~u = f~ ~in~ \Omega~ /~ \Omega_{int}$. Since the outer boundary is not constrained, wouldn't the only Solution to the problem be u=1 in the whole domain, since there is nothing "stopping" the diffusion? Thank you for taking the time!

Comment: The solution with $f=0$ would indeed be $u=1$. But not if $f\neq 0$.

Comment: I should give some background. I'm modelling diffusive Tumor invasion. The circle in the middle represents the currrent tumor profile visible in medical images. My reaction term is a logistic growth like f(u) = u(1-u). Which would let the profile grow until it reaches 1.0. I now want to estimate how far the tumor is spread into the sourrounding tissue. To not disturb the equations, i.e. impose an artificial loss term, I want to add the total volume constraint to 'pin' the solution. But i don't know how to go about global volume constraints.

Comment: @MPIchael assuming you intend your solution to be unique, it's likely you *do* implicitly have a boundary condition on the outer domain, with the most likely candidate being a "no-flux" condition like $\mathbf{n}\cdot\nabla u = 0$. Otherwise there are multiple solutions with a given total volume.